"#ifdef" compilation condition for Kotlin/Native
I'm writing a Kotlin/Native application targeted for Windows, Linux and Mac and I need to call platform.posix._popen on Windows and platform.posix.popen on the other.
If I use a simple conditional (if (Platform.osFamily == OsFamily.WINDOWS)), I get a compile error.

and would you mind sharing that error with us?

@AlexT there's no need. The documentation says "the content of platform.posix is NOT identical on different platforms" and therefore even if you're on Linux and you do if (Platform.osFamily == OsFamily.WINDOWS) platform.posix._popen it will fail to compile, even though the if condition is false, because platform.posix._popen is undefined.

I don't think conditional compilation is supported in Kotlin/Native, but what you have is a multiplatform app and the standard KMP technique is to put Windows-specific code and Linux-specific code in separate directories.

There is no such thing as #ifdef in Kotlin, but you can use the expect/actual mechanism to achieve what you need.
In common code, define an expect fun without a body, and then define an actual fun implementation separately in linux/windows/macOS source sets.
You can find more details about how to do this in the Kotlin multiplatform documentation.

Thanks, @Joffrey. My build wasn't ready for this (the project was made with IntelliJ 2023.1's template) and it was a little hard to make it work. But I managed to make it work :)
